# How to select a list of parents where any of their children matches one of a set of conditions?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have an issue with an NHibernate query I'm making using LINQ, and I'm wondering if it's an unsupported use in NHibernate?

I have a list of parent objects, and I want a list of all of those parents when any of the children meet some set of criteria. To give an example of this, imagine getting a list of parents whom have a child named either John or Sarah.

This is essentially what I'm trying to achieve but I keep getting an error. what I need and the LINQ query I wrote makes total sense, but I'm not sure if I'm pushing the limits of NHibernate's LINQ implementation?

*Sample code*

```
string[] names = {"John", "Sarah"};
session.Query().Where(parent => parent.Children
                  .Any(child => names.Contains(child.FirstName)))
               .ToList();
```

*Suggestions based of comments below, both giving the same error IF names is null.*

```
string[] names = null;
session.Query().Where(parent => names != null && parent.Children
                  .Any(child => names.Contains(child.FirstName)))
               .ToList();

session.Query().Where(parent => parent.Children
                  .Any(child => names != null && names.Contains(child.FirstName)))
               .ToList();
```

I keep getting an error stack that looks something like this...

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast[TResult](IEnumerable source)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ProcessContains.IsEmptyList(HqlParameter source, VisitorParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ProcessContains.Process(ContainsResultOperator resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor queryModelVisitor, IntermediateHqlTree tree)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ResultOperatorProcessor`1.Process(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor queryModel, IntermediateHqlTree tree)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ResultOperatorProcessors.ResultOperatorMap.Process(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModelVisitor queryModel, IntermediateHqlTree tree)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitResultOperator(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperatorBase.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitResultOperators(ObservableCollection`1 resultOperators, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitSubQueryExpression(SubQueryExpression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.Visit(Expression expression, VisitorParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitWhereClause(WhereClause whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitSubQueryExpression(SubQueryExpression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.Visit(Expression expression, VisitorParameters parameters)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitWhereClause(WhereClause whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: Could it be that parent.Children is sometimes null?

Comment: That query should work fine. The only Linq Cast method call in the IsEmptyList method is called on the parameters collection, which is `names` in your case. Are you sure that `names` is not null in your case?

Comment: Did you try to modify your Any part of the query to .Any(child => child != null && names.Contains(child.FirstName))).ToList();

Comment: I still get the same error even when checking for null (see additional examples in querstion. I suppose I could check for null outside of the LINQ statement and then run the query only if it's not-null but I'm not sure how else to do this...

Comment: I was able to keep my original query without any modifications if I added a line above it that read as such... `if(names == null) names = new string[0];` I simply can't do the check in the LINQ query, its evaluation of checking for non-null source collections on the LINQ extension methods is too eager. If you want to write up a quick answer @cremor, I'll credit you for pointing me in the direction of the names collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query should work fine. The only Linq `Cast` method call in the `IsEmptyList` method is called on the parameters collection, which is `names` in your case. Are you sure that `names` is not null?